# Bracha - Al Mitzvas Tefilin - does it count for the 100 daily Brachos

Tags: halacha, blessing, tefilin

[Saying 100 Berachoth in a day](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/10170/saying-100-berachoth-in-a-day)

There is a Mitzva to say 100 Brachos each day. Does the Bracha - Al Mitzvas Tefilin - which those who say it, say immediately Boruch Shem afterwards [Mishna Berura 25:5:21](http://hebrewbooks.org/pdfpager.aspx?req=49623&st=&pgnum=65) - count towards these 100 Brachos?

Comment: Rav Binyamin Tabori stated (I forgot his source) that the Baruch Shem is not for canceling the Berachah, but a line of Shevaḥ for the opportunity to perform the Mitzvah of Tefillin.

Comment: Interesting, never heard that.

Comment: @SethJ I think that is Rav JB Soloveitchik's idea in his Shiurim LeZecher Abba Mari. No exact source though...

Comment: @DoubleAA That is very, very likely. He taught a Shi'ur on Ma'aseh Rav in my Yeshivah, which, I'm pretty sure, is where I heard him say it.

Comment: Do you have any biographical information on Rav Tabori?  I have not heard of him.

Comment: @Adam http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=gkzY7xWEim0&feature=youtube_gdata_player

Comment: And here - http://haretzion.org/faculty/ramim @Adam

Comment: Regarding the nature of this obligation, see: http://seforim.blogspot.com/2016/11/regarding-haftarah-on-simchat-torah-and.html.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The [Mishna Brura in OC 46 sk 14](http://www.hebrewbooks.org/pdfpager.aspx?req=14170&st=&pgnum=147) counts both blessings on tefillin for the 100.